# Batch file looping issue with %ERRORLEVEL%

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:sleep
tasklist /FI "imagename eq mspaint.exe"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto again
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto sleep
:again
echo "Hurray"
PAUSE
exit
```

When mspaint is open, the loop goes on executing as expected, but when i close mspaint, instead of getting the echo "Hurray". I continuously get the message :

```
INFO : No Tasks are running that match the specified criteria
INFO : No Tasks are running that match the specified criteria
```

How can I solve this ? My requirement is to run an installer and check if process exists, once it has ended the batch file proceeds ahead and does post install tasks.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Editing to provide the solution and adding **SOLVED** to the title is not how StackOverflow works. Please post an actual answer that provides that information instead, so that people can see it when they find the question in the future. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions, and you can even (after a suitable delay) accept it as the correct one. (You don't earn rep for it, of course.) The [help] has more information about answering questions, including your own. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ken, I am new to the forum, hence slowly getting to its rules.
Solution : I achieved this after some hit and trials.

```
:sleep
ping -n 5 127.1.1.0 >nul
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq mspaint.exe" | find /I /N "mspaint.exe"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto sleep
```

** remainder code for batch file post mspaint is closed **
Also ** the ping statement is a poor man's code for waiting 5 seconds